# What could cause this bizarre Lion behavior?

Tags: osx-lion, crash

This is a Core i7 MacBook Pro that was upgraded to Lion from Snow Leopard, retaining the legacy FileVault encryption on the home directory.

I've been getting these strange lockups, three or four times now over the course of two weeks, where some part of the system suddenly breaks, producing the following behavior:

- Can still make new SSH connections into the machine
- The display is completely frozen, except that the trackpad still moves the cursor around
- Nothing happens when I close the lid
- Music from a Flash app in Safari continues to play

It doesn't appear to be triggered by any specific action from me.

This has never happened to me on my Core i7 MacBook Air at home, which was preloaded with Lion. The only major difference I can think of is the FileVault difference. Could that cause this? What else I should investigate? I can't imagine that a hardware issue would cause such a specific combination of symptoms.

Comment: [Is it a Mid-2010 model, by any chance?](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4088)

Comment: "About This Mac" says "Early 2011".

Comment: I don't know, but [it's still a problem](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3194165?start=1350&tstart=0). I haven't experienced this on my 2011 Macbook Pro 13" (yet).

Comment: You still have two graphics cards. Try [restricting it to only use the integrated one](http://codykrieger.com/gfxCardStatus) for a while and see if the problem persists.

Comment: interesting, didn't know about that. thanks for the tip.

Comment: Seems like I'm unable to switch to Integrated Only; it keeps switching back to Discrete Only.

Comment: Do all crashes occur while you're playing flash video?

Comment: My crashes have never involved flash video. In the case I mentioned in the original post, it was audio-only. I have also just gotten a crash where I was using only TextMate and Terminal.

Comment: My iMac started doing this and I blamed Flash for a month. Then I checked my hard drive and discovered it was damaged and I needed a new one.

Comment: Randolph: your hard drive caused this same behavior, where the display locks up but everything else (including SSH, music, etc) still works?